# Coroutines in Magic Methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, coroutine, magic-methods

let's say, I've got a magic Method in Python 3.6 like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=self)
```

Now I want to add a Coroutine into it, something like:

```
async def __str__(self):
    await self.my_coro(args)
    return 'a {self.color} car'.format(self=self)
```

As far as I know, it is necessary to add async before def, but this seems not to work with magic Methods. Is there an (easy) workaround or totally impossible?

Comment: This would require that all consumers (callers) of this API will handle it as an async method, which is not defined in its behaviour. In other words, nobody expects `__str__` to be async, so nobody will `await` it, so this won't work. This isn't specific to magic methods really, you'll have this every time you're implementing an already defined interface.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, specifically? In the example with `__str__` it doesn't seem necessary to use `await` in order to return a formatted string.

Comment: Not to mention that a method like `__str__` shouldn't be so complex/expensive as to include an async call.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I wanted to replace a sync function into a coroutine in a project. But the rat tail is realy long (because now I have to make await statements everywhere the old function/new coroutine was/is used etc.), so I try to  replace every sync method with an async method, but my dead end is a `__exit__` Method.

Comment: See [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with).

Comment: @zonk Are you asking for special methods *in general*  or context managers *in specific*?

Comment: @mkrieger1 tbh I have no clue about Asynchrounous context managers. I'll have a look on it, if this could be a usefull hint for the problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In my case it is a special method and I believe I will hit other special methods as well, so I would say _"special methods in general"_

Comment: `__enter__` and `__exit__` are used to implement context managers. If you feel the need to use `await` in them, then you need an asynchronous context manager, which you can implement either by replacing those methods with `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` or by using one of the solutions from the question I've linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: There is no workaround as Python expects a specific type for many special methods. However, some special methods have async variants.

---

An `async def` function is fundamentally a different kind of function. Similar to how a generator function evaluates to a generator, a coroutine function evaluates to an awaitable.

You can define special methods to be async, but that affects their return type. In the case of `__str__`, you get an `Awatable[str]` instead of a bare `str`. Since Python *requires* a `str` here, this results in an error.

```
>>> class AStr:
...     async def __str__(self):
...         return 'Hello Word'
>>> str(AStr())

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type coroutine)
```

This affects all special methods that are directly interpreted by Python: These include `__str__`, `__repr__`, `__bool__`, `__len__`, `__iter__`, `__enter__` and some others. Usually, if a special method relates to some internally used functionality (e.g. `str` for direct display) or statement (e.g. `for` needing an iterator) it cannot be `async`.

---

Some special methods are not directly interpreted by Python. Examples include arithmetic operators (`__add__`, `__sub__`, ...), comparisons (`__lt__`, `__eq__`, ...) and lookup (`__get__`, `__getattribute__`, ...). Their return type can be any object, including awaitables.

You can define such special methods via `async def`. This affects their return type, but only requires client code to `await` them. For example, you can define `+` to be used as `await (a + b)`.

```
>>> def AWAIT(awaitable):
...     """Basic event loop to allow synchronous ``await``"""
...     coro = awaitable.__await__()
...     try:
...         while True:
...             coro.send(None)
...     except StopIteration as e:
...         return e.args[0] if e.args else None
...
>>> class APlus:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     async def __add__(self, other):
...         return self.value + other
...
>>> async def add(start, *values):
...     total = start
...     for avalue in map(APlus, values):
...         total = await (avalue + total)
...     return total
...
>>> AWAIT(add(5, 10, 42, 23))
80
```

---

A few special methods exist for the `await` machinery and are expected to return an awaitable. This includes `__aenter__`, `__aexit__`, and `__anext__`. Notably, `__await__` must return an iterator, not an awaitable.

You can (and in most cases should) define these methods as `async def`. If you need asynchronous capabilities in the corresponding sync special method, *use the corresponding async special method* with `async def`. For example, you can define an asynchronous context manager.

```
>>> class AContext:
...     async def __aenter__(self):
...         print('async enter')
...     async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
...         print('async exit')
...
>>> async def scoped(message):
...     async with AContext():
...         print(message)
...
>>> AWAIT(scoped("Hello World"))
async enter
Hello World
async exit
```